# Did Palpatine have the very same powers as Darth Plagueis?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, darth-sidious

In the Senate, and later again in his office, chancellor Palpatine tells Anakin how Darth Plagueis taught him everything before being slain by Palpatine. Does this include the power to save lives and to make midi-chlorians create life? Palpatine later tells Anakin (now Darth Vader) that only Plagueis was capable of this, which is a contradiction to his former statements, but that when working together they can lift the veil. How much power did Palpatine / Darth Sidious have over the midi-chlorians?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends at what point in time and what you mean by that.

By *Return of the Jedi*, I’m sure he could do everything Plagueis could do and better. He spent so long studying and advancing his knowledge. He created life in Snoke and successfully cloned a powerful Force user. That’s something everybody who tried had trouble with. He also would’ve had more time to read through Plaguesis stuff. Palpatine said he can’t bring Padme back to life once she died, but before that he probably could’ve kept her alive.

However, if you’re saying it like were they the exact same, then the answer is a definite no. Palpatine far eclipsed his former master, and likely knew many things Plagueis did not.

Comment: The Revenge of the Sith should be called "Return of the Sith" and Return of the Jedi "Revenge of the Jedi", just my two pence or something. And I'm unsure whether I'm willing to consider the three Disney sequels canon.

Comment: Revenge is not the Jedi way.

Comment: @suchiuomizu It is not a Jedi goal but do they really hold on to it? It's the Jedi Luke and the rebels who attacked the 2nd death star first. The Empire just tried to maintain/restore peache in the galaxy. At the end of episode III it's the only time peace was achieved throughout the galaxy, Anakin fulfilling his destiny as the chosen one when defeating Gunray and the separatists. No other of the six episodes ended in peace entirely (except episode I perhaps, thanks to young Anakin and a bit also Palpatine a.o. but there remained the corrupt senate and courts).